# How do i convert hdb file? ... believed to be from act! source

Tags: act

Any ideas ?

I think the original source was a goldmine database, looking around it appears that the file was likely built using an application called ACT which I gather is a huge product I don't really want to be deploying for a one off file total size less than 5 meg.

So ...

Anyone know of a simple tool that I can run this file through to convert it to a standard CSV or something?

It does appear to be (when looking at it in notepad and excel) in some sort of csv type format but it's like the data is encrypted somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is weird,

I got a little confused because the data looked a complete mess, in actual fact the mess was the data, that's what it was meant to look like.

Simply put, i opened the file in notepad, seemed to have a sort of pattern so i droppped it on excel.

Apparently excel has no issues reading these files ... strange huh !!!

Comment: did you use File>Open to open the file ?
or did you droped the content on excel ? i also have a similar file and want to open it, but cannot find how.

Comment: it was a long time ago but i think i just drag and dropped it on excel ... if that dont work try open it through file open ... you may have to change the filter option in the open ialog though to "all files"

Comment: i tried File>Open and it dosent work :\ will try later today to drag and drop, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any third party tooling for opening these files specifically, although there is an SDK available for C# which could resolve your problem with a little elbow grease.

The SDK can be aquired for free [Here](http://www.act.com/partners/development-partner-program/)

Also there is a developer forum which could provide some valuable resources including training material with sample code [Here](http://community.act.com/)

Resources will be provided with the SDK

Also, out of interest since ACT is a Sage product have you any Sage software floating about which you could attempt to access the data with? Most offices have!

Failing all of the above there is a trial available for ACT! [Here!](http://www.act.com/lp/trial/)

Good luck with your problem!

Comment: The force is strong with this one ... however i don't believe sage is the answer on the basis that I have been informed that the file actually came from goldmine, having said that ... I looked in to our sage software and apparently Sage and act are completely separate prodcuts.

Comment: All the links in answer are not found can you please update it.

Comment: Sorted, although this question is 4 years old!